# Random Queue in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I've written this code with all correct understandings i have. please check my problems.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

// Define a structure for the dequeue elements

This structure is all good, with data, next, previous pointers.

```
typedef struct RanElmt_ {

    void *data;
    struct DeqElmt_ *prev;
    struct DeqElmt_ *next;

    void (*destroy)(void *data);



//Your Code here
} RanElmt;
```

THis is ok too, acording to what i think is correct.

```
typedef struct RandQ_{
    int size;
    struct RanElmt *head;
    struct RanElmt *tail; 



}RandQ;



RandQ * RandomizedQueue(void (*destroy)(void *data)){

    RandQ *relmt = (RandQ*)malloc(sizeof(RandQ));



}     // construct an empty randomized queue


int isREmpty(RandQ *rQ){
    if ( rQ->size == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}                                  // is the queue empty?

int rsize(RandQ *rQ){

    return rQ->size;

}    
                             // return the number of items on the queue
```

ACtually this is only one function,(enqueue) I'm going to get the idea and code other functions(dequeue, sample etc..)

```
int enqueue(RandQ *rQ, const void *data){
    RanElmt *relmt = (RanElmt*)malloc(sizeof(RanElmt));
    relmt->data = (void*)data;
    if (rQ->head == NULL){
        relmt = rQ->head;
        relmt = rQ->tail;
        relmt->prev = NULL;
        relmt->next = NULL;
    }
    else{
        rQ->head = relmt;
    }

    (rQ->head)->prev = relmt;
    relmt->prev = rQ->head;
    rQ->head = relmt;

}                // add the item




main(){

    Deque(free);


    printf(" okk \n");
}
```

THis program is giving these errors:

[Errors i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbcLb.png)

Comment: Try to change `(rQ->head)->prev = relmt;` to `rQ->head->prev = relmt;`

Comment: @Maraboc: The arrow operator is left-associated, so the two variants are the same.

Comment: `struct RanElmt` is undefined. There only is `struct RanElmt_` and `RanElmt` in the code you show. So what?

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)` at least, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

In C struct tags and type names live in different name spaces. That is `struct RanElmt` and `RanElmt` are two different types, in addition `struct RanElmt` is not completely defined.

Your `RandQ` should be defined something like

```
typedef struct RandQ_{
    int size;
    struct RanElmt_ *head; // or RanElmt* head;
    struct RanElmt_ *tail; // or RanElmt* tail;

}RandQ;
```

in addition your `RanElmt` is probably not what you want, maybe you meant:

```
typedef struct RanElmt_ {

    void *data;
    struct RanElmt_ *prev; // pointer to a struct of the same type
    struct RanElmt_ *next; // pointer to a struct of the same type

    void (*destroy)(void *data);

   // You cannot put code here in C (or even a function definition AFAIK).
} RanElmt;
```

Comment: thanks, got it. this typedef thing is confusing. what's its purpose ?

Comment: I can agree on that. I think the best approach is to use the same name as tag and typename (ie `typedef struct RanElmt { ... } RanElmt`) as the language allows that due to this. I don't know the rationale for this, but you probably have to dig deep in historical record to find that out (has been like this since the 80s at least).

Answer (score 0):

You have confused the struct tag and the typedeffed alias for the queue elements in the definition of the queue:

```
typedef struct RandQ_{
    int size;
    struct RanElmt *head;
    struct RanElmt *tail; 
} RandQ;
```

Here, the head and tail are of the type `struct RanElmt`. This struct doesn't exist in your program. You have a `struct RanElmt_` (with trailing underscore) that you can also call ´RanElmt`without the`struct`keyword, because you have combined the struct definition with a`typedef`.

The compiler still generates the code, because pointers to unknown structs are okay, unless you try to get at their data. Obviously the compiler can't access the struct fields if it doesn't know them.

There's no need for the underscore. The names of structs are in a separate namespace, so you can have both a struct called `RandQ` and a type (in global namespace) called `RanQ`. I recommend to use the same name for struct tag and aliassed type.

You can also get rid of the need to use the `struct` keyword inside the struct defnition if you separate the `typedef` from the struct definition:

```
typedef struct RanElmt RanElmt;      // use just RanElmt from now on

struct RanElmt {
    void *data;
    RanElmt *prev;
    RanElmt *next;
} RanElmt;
```

Your code has several other problems, but I think he program is in an early state, so I don't address them here.

Comment: thanks anyway. can we use the without underscore name of struct?

Comment: Yes. With `typedef struct X X` you create an alias `X` for the type `struct X`.